# SQLAlchemy Unsupported Type Issue Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bots

I have the following setup:

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///offences.db'
offencedb = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Offences(offencedb.Model):
      id = offencedb.Column(offencedb.Integer, primary_key=True)
      nick = offencedb.Column(offencedb.String(100), unique=True)
      offences = offencedb.Column(offencedb.Integer)  

      def __init__(self, nick, offences):
          self.nick = nick
          self.offences = offences

      def __repr__(self):
          return '<Nick %r>' % self.nick
```

If I try to use the model in the following way:

```
offencesquery = Offences.query.filter_by(nick = nick).first()
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

But nick is a string and the database has the nick column as a string...

Comment: Hi! You've done a great job creating a code sample that demonstrates your problem. I've modified your question a bit (I removed some of the stuff that isn't relevant to the question, and removed "IRC BOT" from the title, since while in your case you are doing this for a bot, others might encounter this same issue but not be writing an IRC bot (so that title would be a bit distracting).

Comment: Thanks, no problem - i can see your point. :) i'll remember next time

Comment: I have just run your code on my setup, and am not experiencing the issue. Can you complete your code sample, including how you define your "nick" variable?

Comment: here is the library, https://github.com/necavi/Serva/tree/master/Libraries - eg. the you can see how everything is defined there. Regards to code - github link is coming up once i update it

Comment: Please don't post the link to an entire github repository, it doesn't help us get to the problem. We would have to dig through some source code (which will change when someone else comes to this question later). StackOverflow questions should be completely encapsulated: if we need to read some code on another site to understand what the question is asking, then it's not a good question. This mentality helps us get to the root of the problem. In any case, I still am not convinced that "nick" is a string. Can you do a `print type(nick)` right before your query?

Comment: im using python 3.3 so i tried print(type(nick)) and it results in <class 'Libraries.biblib.nickclass'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we saw in your comments, when you did `print(type(nick))`, we found out that the value for `nick` was NOT actually a string, like you had assumed. Instead, it was a `Libraries.biblib.nickclass` object. Therefore, when you did...

```
offencesquery = Offences.query.filter_by(nick = nick).first()
```

...you were basically trying to create a SQL query for all Offences where the `nick` field has the value of a Python object (the `nickclass` object). This doesn't make sense: SQL doesn't understand objects, it understand strings and integers and such. SQLAlchemy tried to convert that object into something that SQL could understand and it failed. Thus, the error message. If you had written...

```
nick = 'Test'
offencesquery = Offences.query.filter_by(nick = nick).first()
```

...then your code would have worked. Perhaps your `nickclass` object has a `nickname` attribute or something that you can use for your string?

Comment: okay, for but nick is passed as a variable, so i cant do nick = "Blah" How do i get around this :) thanks a lot btw

Comment: Well, that's up to you to figure out. Surely somewhere in your code you have access the actual string you are trying to find. You can't write a SQL script to find a name if you don't know what name you are looking for. Based on [this code](https://github.com/necavi/Serva/blob/master/Libraries/biblib.py#L11) you probably would need to do `nick.nick`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining everything thoroughly :D